# Is teleportation circle two-way?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, teleportation

If I want to send a strike team through a *teleportation circle* and get them back home, would I need to send the wizard who cast the *circle* with the strike team to cast *teleportation circle* again when strike team wants to return? Or can the strike team use the *teleportation circle* they arrived from to make the return trip?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The spell [*teleportation circle*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/teleportationCircle.html) creates a one-way effect. Returning the strike team to base requires them to find their own way back, be that with the wizard who cast the spell *teleportation circle* or some other means.

Comment: You can, however, use the Teleport Circle itself as a locate, so long as your familiarize yourself with it prior to your strike team departure. You might also be able to make use of some kind of recall effect, if you can manage the communication angle.